# javascript:OpenPopUpPage inside my Sharepoint will not work with google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have added the following code inside a script editor web part, to show a pop up when clicking on Camera link:-

```
<li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera</a></li>
```

The pop-up will be shown well on IE and firefox, while it will be shown as if it is minimized when opening the pop-up using google chrome web browser, as shown below:-

[image]

So what might be causing this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the callback parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410825(v=office.14).aspx

```
<li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726', null, 1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but adding the call back function, will ignore the height and width setting..

Comment: And if you use a method with no parameters at all. <a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/');" unselectable="on">Camera</a>. The window also displays minimized or it has a normal size